# How secure is my Windows user profile folder?

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, user-profiles

On my work computer (which has BitLocker enabled), I have a user profile folder with lots of `.` folders in it, such as .jenkins and .jira and .gradle.  These have program settings, but also things that should be secure like private/public key pairs.

Just how secure is this user profile folder?

Can another user on the system get access to it?

Can an admin user get access to it?

What about a badly-behaving program that I've run?  Can any malicious program get access to that folder, or only one running as admin?

Answer (score 1):

It's somewhat secure.

> Can another user on the system get access to it?

Yes and no. Not from Windows, filesystem permissions won't let them. But if they have physical access to the computer and you're not using full disk encryption, then they can boot to Linux and browse these files freely.

> Can an admin user get access to it?

Yes, even from Windows.

> What about a badly-behaving program that I've run?

If you can access these files, so can programs. If you don't need elevated privileges (the UAC prompt), programs don't need them too. As always you shouldn't run software that you don't trust.

---

I'd highly advise enabling full disk encryption if your threat model involves actors trying to access these files by means of physical access. If you have the Pro edition of Windows, you can use Bitlocker which has excellent Windows integration. For regular edition VeraCrypt is good, but not as user friendly and upgrading Windows encrypted with VC is quite tricky.

Comment: You should mention, that full disk encryption changes nothing concerning other users or rogue programs accessing the folders. You did qualify it with "if your threat model ...", but it might easily be misread.

Comment: FDE is not going to protect the author's files from an Administrator on the machine.  As the Administrator would have access to the drive at that point.  Once you are logged into a Windows machine, if we are talking about the system disk, the Administrator would be able to access any files on the drive.

Comment: As I'm the only one who uses this PC, I'm not very concerned about another user or an admin on the machine, and much more concerned about a malicious program.  (But I don't have a habit of installing malicious programs.)

Comment: @Kyralessa - I am confused.  In your question, it specifically asked if another user and/or Administrator can access your files that exist within your profile directory, that does not seem to gel with the fact you have a single user on the system.

Comment: Still there are dirty ways to access the files. Any person who has physical access to the computer can burn a live Linux distribution in a USB flash drive, CD or DVD and live boot from it. Then he or she will boot from it and can access NTFS partitions without installing any other additional drivers or softwares. And if your system has more than one operating systems (especially windows or Linux distros) the procedure is even much easier. He can boot from it and access (maybe harm) your files. EFS is not good, disk encryption using bitlocker is a good choice. Then the hacker will be screwed.

Comment: @Wasif_Hasan - How exactly is encrypting each individual file, with a certificate only the user is able to provide, not a good security solution?  Linux certainly wouldn't be able to decrypt those files without the certificate.

Answer (score 1):

> Just how secure is this user profile folder?

You can assume anyone with physical access to your machine will be able to access unencrypted files on your system.  Since you have BitLocker you limit this to anyone who has the BitLocker recovery key and/or the BitLocker passphrase.

If you were to enable Encrypted File System (EFS) within Windows, you would encrypt each individual file within your profile, this would further limit access to the files to those with the certificate used to encrypt the file.  It is possible to configure both BitLocker and EFS in such a way where it allows an Administrator to have access to your files.  Since you only have a single account that situation is not really applicable.  The only way an Administrator would be able to access your files is if they had a working account themselves.

> Can another user on the system get access to it?

You can assume anyone with physical access to your machine will be able to access unencrypted files on your system.  In order to access your files, the individual would need access to another Windows machine, in order to take ownership of the files in question.  A user can also use Linux on your own machine to access your files.  If this theoretical user had access to your BitLocker recovery key, it would be possible to access your files, by simply disabling BitLocker protection.  Since you only have a single account that situation is not really applicable.

> Can an admin user get access to it?

A privilege Windows user can take ownership of any file owned by another user.  It takes less than 30 seconds to take ownership of a user's file.

> What about a badly-behaving program that I've run?

**Malicious applications have the same privileges as the user.**  This is the reason Randsomware is extremely dangerous.  A normal user typically has write access to every file they consider important.  Most Randsomware only target files user's have write access to.

> Can any malicious program get access to that folder, or only one running as admin?

A malicious program has access to any program the user has access to.  **If that user is an Administrator, then if the malicious application uses an exploit to elevate it's permissions, then it also has elevated permissions and access to any file it wants.**